# Return and throw on one line without semi-colon

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to return a fat-arrow anon function, run a conditional, return an error if it's false and return true if it's true all on one line, WITHOUT a semi-colon?

```
let example = (d) => { if (get(d, 'facebook_user.id')) return true; throw new Error('Missing `facebook_id` from request') }
```

I'm trying to find a better way of writing the above without a semi-colon, the restriction is I have to return and throw. Ideas? Thoughts?

Comment: What possibly real-world situation lead to this restriction? Reading this question, all I can think is: **Why?** All of that logic belongs on multiple lines. Slamming it into one line adds absolutely no benefit while making it extremely difficult to read.

Comment: The **better** way of writing this code is to not cram it into one line in the first place.

Comment: Put curly braces around the `return true`, and you won't need a semicolon. Though you're not returning an error; you're throwing immediately. The *Why?* is begging to be asked, however.

Comment: @squint Alternatively, drop *all* braces and build a single expression, and ES6's `=>` syntax makes the result of that expression the return value of the function: `example = (d) => get(d, '...') && true || eval('throw new Error("missing!")')` Again, *never do this*, but it's technically correct...

Comment: @meagar: True... unpleasant but correct. Other forms of `eval` are usable as well, as is abstracting the `throw` into a separate function.

Comment: I am genuinely curious if it's possible. I'm curious about javascript as a language and trying to learn. I've heeded all your warnings, but would still appreciate an answer. Not happy about this being down voted out the gate.

Comment: Thomas: If this is just a curiosity, I totally get it. It can be interesting to know what syntactic possibilities are available in a language. There's real academic merit to that, even when the requirements are a bit odd. Probably a good idea to make that clear from the start though. I think people will be less inclined to down vote it when they understand your intent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about below?

```
let example = (d) => { get(d, 'facebook_user.id') || (() => {throw new Error('Missing `facebook_id` from request')})() };
```

Answer (score 3):

One can create a function that wraps the condition and the error message and throws / returns.

```
export function ifThrow (condition, errorMessage) {
  if (condition) throw new Error(errorMessage)
  return true
}

let check_facebook_id = (d) => ifThrow(!get(d, 'facebook_id'), 'Missing `facebook_id`')
```